# Web API 2 Controller isn't picking up IPrincipal.User.Identity.Name

Tags: .net, api, permissions, active-directory

I'm working on setting up permissions for my Web API 2 and I've ran into an issue that I've been looking at for quite some time.

When I run my application locally I am unable to get the current user name on my `ApiController` by using the `IPrincipal.User` method. What I want to do with this is to search for the user within my AD and then filter the groups returned to determine if the user has access to certain access to different web pages.

To overcome not being able to get the current user using the `IPrincipal` class I have used the `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;`. This works but I can't understand why I can't use the `IPrincipal` class to achieve the same out.

**Foot note:**

Do I need to configure my ApiController in a certain way for the User to return from the `IPrincipal` class?

In Web.Config file I have set the following authentication mode:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by `IPrincipal.User`? `IPrincipal` is an interface, so it doesn't have any properties.

Comment: @GabrielLuci within my ApiController if I type 'User' it then gives a list of methods that I can call and it says that it's part of the following: System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal ApiController.User

Comment: @GabrielLuci furthermore, I have seen examples where if you call User.Identity.Name it returns the current name of the user but in my case its blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to fix the issue and it was one that was helped by using the following website:

https://spikesapps.wordpress.com/2016/09/08/how-to-implement-windows-authentication-in-an-angularjs-application-with-a-stand-alone-web-api/.

Basically I had to access the hidden .vs folder from my project location. Within there I went to config and then edited the `applicationhost` file. I then applied the following to the end of the config file:

```
<location path="AccidentReporting.Web">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
<location path="AccidentReporting.API">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

You can see I've added the location proper twice and that's because within my solution I've two projects, one for hosting the API and the other for hosting the WEB application.

So now within my `API Controller` I an access the user identity name by using the `User.Identity.Name` method.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is not authenticated, [`Request.LogonUserIdentity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.logonuseridentity?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Web_HttpRequest_LogonUserIdentity) will show you the user that the web server is running under. For example, in IIS that might be `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR`. On your development machine, if you're running IIS Express, that may be your user account. However, if the user is authenticated, then that changes to be the credentials of the user accessing the site.

However, the [`Controller.User`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.user(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.User) property will only show you the credentials of the user. If the user is not authenticated, it will be blank.

Once the user is authenticated, both will be the same.

(I just tested this now and that's the behavior I see)

So it sounds like the user is not being authenticated. Do you have anonymous authentication enabled still?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So when I use `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity` I can see the credentials of the current user including the domain name. I also see that I'm running under `NT AUTHORITY`. This also returns `IsAnonymous` as false. Furthermore to your authentication question I have set `<authentication mode="Windows" />` in my Web.config file. I've also checked that when I run 'User.Identity.IsAnonymous` that it's returning true and I'm not sure why. I'm still stuck on this issue.